# SAS - Creating macro variables with a 'select into' which consists of other macro variables

Tags: sas

Can someone please help me.
I have the code below. It does not generate an error but at the same time does not achieve what I want it to.
The intention is to create macro variables for each cell across a number of columns using a 'Select into'. I think the problem is the fact that the 'Select into' contains macro variables too.

```
%macro ld_macrovar;
  proc sql noprint;
select count(portfolio)
    into :a
    from split_D;

   %do i=1 %to &max_comb.; /*already defined elsewhere -actual value=2 */

  select _&i.LGD
    into :_&i.LGD1 - :_&i.LGD%left(&a)
    from split_D;
   %end;
quit;
%mend;
%ld_macrovar;
```

Thanks

Comment: that should work.  What do you get in the log when you turn on the `mprint` option (`options mprint;`)?

Answer (score 2):

Your macro variables are being assigned to the local scope of the macro. So if you want to access them outside the macro you will have to manually assign them to the global scope. This can be achieved by using the [`%global` statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1lhhti7fjxgb1n1fuiubqk11h4d.htm). Alternatively you can perform the processing that requires the macro variables inside the macro.

You can check the scope of your variables by running [`%put _ALL_;` or `%put _USER_`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000206943.htm).

```
%macro ld_macrovar(max_comb);
    proc sql noprint;
        select count(*) into :rows
        from split_D;
    quit;
    %do i = 1 %to &max_comb.;
        %do j = 1 %to &rows.;
            %global  _&i.LGD&j.;
        %end;
    %end;
    proc sql noprint;
        %do i = 1 %to &max_comb.;
            select _&i.LGD
            into :_&i.LGD1 -
            from split_D;
        %end;
    quit;
%mend;
/* Dummy data */
data split_D;
    do i = 1 to 10;
        _1LGD = i**2;
        _2LGD = exp(i);
        output;
    end;
run;
%ld_macrovar(2);
/* Print out all the user defined macro variables */
%put _USER_;
```

---

You can also avoid the need to use `%left` with `&a` by adding the [`trimmed`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1tupenuhmu1j0n19d3curl9igt4.htm) option to your fist `into` statement (in SAS 9.3 and later or `separated by ""` in other versions).

---

A word of caution: If you are planning to use the values for further analysis or there are a lot of rows there ma be a better way to achieve what you want. Macro variables store only text and when the values are stored some precision may be lost. In general it's best to use data sets for moving/manipulating data and macro variables for when you need to parametrise your code.